# Group consecutive/sequential numbers from array into string

Tags: objective-c, sequence

I'd like to take an array of NSNumbers [11,12,13,24,10,25,26,41,30] and return a NSString that looks like the following Groups: 10-13,24-26,30 & 41

Any direction on how I can accomplish this? I tried sorting the array, then checking if the next item in the array was +1 to tell if it was consecutive. But after that I did not know how to deal with this array when there was only 1 number (which can happen) or handle the last number either. Nor the grouping for NSString purposes.

Comment: Update your question with your current attempted code. Clearly explain what issues you are having with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at any problem in its entirety can easily seem overwhelming. However, if you break it down into smaller and even an intermediate piece, you will get the response you're looking for.

I think you're on the right track:

1. sort the array.
2. Create a mutable array to store the 'groupings' of the string.
3. check the array for consecutive.
4. add loners ("30") and consecutives ("10-13") as strings to the mutable array.
5. When you get to the end of the processing, check that this intermediate array contains four elements: ["10-13", "24-26", "30", "41"].
6. Next, process the array of strings into the output string.
7. Handle the final "&" part.

If you've solved the problem for the test case ( [11,12,13,24,10,25,26,41,30] ), then you can see what happens with the single number edge case and then tune your method to properly handle it.

Answer (score 0):

`NSIndexSet` is specialized for that. Add your numbers to `NSMutableIndexSet`, then use [enumerateRangesUsingBlock](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsindexset/1409668-enumeraterangesusingblock?language=objc) to build the string.

Comment: I thought so first, too, but `NSIndexSet` doesn't let you enumerate ranges of consecutive indexes.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Sure it does. Using `NSIndexSet` makes this a trivial problem to solve.

Comment: @rmaddy Wow, I thought so, then I checked and didn't find it wondering, why I though so first. Likely I need glasses.