# Why does NS predicate failing to parse my conditional statement on NSArray Index

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsarray, nspredicate

I am retrieving web data via an api, using jsonSerialization.

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
```

Then I am able to get desired data using following predicate.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"value == 1 && day = 0"]; 
NSArray *filteredArray = [[jsonArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] valueForKey:@"hour"];
```

This gives me an filteredArray of the data I want.

> filteredArray = ( 0, 1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 14, 15, 16, 17 )

From this filteredArray I need to extract start and end of all the continuous numbers. For example in the above array these are (0, 2, 7, 9, 14, 18). I am trying to achieve this using second predicate on my filteredArray, by passing the array index as condition.

```
 NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"if (filteredArray[1] - filteredArray[0] !=0)"];
```

This is crashing my program. I thought I can pass the array index that way to a predicate ?

Comment: Your first predicate gets every array element where `value == 1 && day = 0`. A predicate can't get every `filteredArray` element where `if (filteredArray[1] - filteredArray[0] !=0)`. See [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789) and [Predicate Format String Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795).

Comment: Similar question: [Group consecutive/sequential numbers from array into string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49720612/group-consecutive-sequential-numbers-from-array-into-string/49722038#49722038).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSPredicate` is the wrong API to filter ranges.

I recommend to convert the indexes to `NSIndexSet` and enumerate the ranges

```
NSMutableIndexSet *indexSet = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
for (NSNumber *index in filteredArray) {
    [indexSet addIndex:index.unsignedIntegerValue];
}
[indexSet enumerateRangesUsingBlock:^(NSRange range, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
     NSLog(@"%ld, %ld", range.location, range.length);
}];
```